# Replacing contents of html page using another html page

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am trying to avoid header, sidebar info repeating of my html page template.

So, I was thinking to user `innerHTML` to replace the contents on the fly. However, I do not want to put entire target html on the same page under `innerHTML` as it will be nightmare to debug or maintain later.

So, is there a way to specify the another page link in the `innerHtml` and have contents separate?

just as an example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function replacePage(page){
      var ele = document.getElementById('page-wrapper'); ele.innerHTML = "<div>hey vik</div>";
     }
    </script>
```

I'm looking if i can specify the `innerHTML` value as some .html file name and move the `<div>hey vik</div>` there.

Comment: This is what a template library is for https://garann.github.io/template-chooser/

Comment: Check out Mustache.js : https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

Comment: not simple enough to do this without any other library etc?

Comment: This is where starting to use server-sided code will come in handy. You should try anything that isn't PHP.

Comment: You could store all of the "other" html values as Javascript, or you can hit up server side code for an answer.  But as with most things roll-your-own on the server-side you have to just be a little careful about security.

Answer (score 0):

ok guys i finally used jquery to do this. What I did was instead of loaded content part, i actually moved the static part into a .html file and then loaded it via jquery as

$(function() {

$("#includedContent").load("navbar.html"); 
 };

the place where i need to rander it i added as below

```
<div id="includedContent"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.documentElement` to select the root element of the document and the store it in a variable:

```
let content = document.documentElement;
```

And then use `innerHTML` to change the page content:

```
content.innerHTML = "<body><h1>text</h1><body>";
```